# tensorflow.js in webworkers

Tags: javascript, web-worker, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I want to import 2 scripts in webWorker by importScripts() as follows,but it failed to import. How to deal with it?

```
self.importScripts('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs');
self.importScripts('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-converter');
```

[error figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uduZU.png)

Comment: Is there any error you get?

Comment: now i'm failed to import the tfjs script library use self.importScripts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible to use the webgl implementation on web-worker, the offlineCanvas being an experimental features. However, it is possible to use the CPU backend.

Here is an example of delegation to the web-worker to perform a computation

```html
<head>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.14.2/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        const worker_function = () => {

            onmessage =  () => {
                console.log('from web worker')
                    this.window = this
                    importScripts('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/setimmediate@1.0.5/setImmediate.min.js')
                    importScripts('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.10.3')
                    tf.setBackend('cpu')
                    
                    const res = tf.zeros([1, 2]).add(tf.ones([1, 2]))
                    res.print()
                    
                    postMessage({res: res.dataSync(), shape: res.shape})
            };
        }
        if (window != self)
            worker_function();
    </script>
    <script>
        const worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(["(" + worker_function.toString() + ")()"], { type: 'text/javascript' })));
        worker.postMessage({});
        worker.onmessage = (message) => {
         console.log('from main thread')
         const {data} = message
         tf.tensor(data.res, data.shape).print()
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

With tensors the data shared between the main thread and the web worker can be big. This data is either cloned or transferred.

The difference is that if the data is cloned, the web worker will still keep a copy of the data for further processing. When transfer, the ownership of the data is transferred as well. Its advantage compare to cloning is the fastness of the transfer, actually it can be viewed as a passing to reference (if ones come from a background of language with pointer)

Let's discuss the performance with these two snippets

```html
<head>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.14.2/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        const worker_function = () => {

            onmessage =  () => {
                console.log('from web worker')
                    this.window = this
                    importScripts('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/setimmediate@1.0.5/setImmediate.min.js')
                    importScripts('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.10.3')
                    tf.setBackend('cpu')
                    
                    const res = tf.randomNormal([2000, 2000, 3])
                    const t0 = performance.now()
                    postMessage({res: res.dataSync().buffer, shape: res.shape}, [res.dataSync().buffer])
                    console.log(`Prediction took ${(performance.now() - t0).toFixed(1)} ms`)
            };
        }
        if (window != self)
            worker_function();
    </script>
    <script>
        const worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(["(" + worker_function.toString() + ")()"], { type: 'text/javascript' })));
        worker.postMessage({});
        worker.onmessage = (message) => {
         console.log('from main thread')
         const {data} = message
         tf.tensor(new Float32Array(message.data.res), message.data.shape)
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

```html
<head>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.14.2/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        const worker_function = () => {

            onmessage =  () => {
                console.log('from web worker')
                    this.window = this
                    importScripts('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/setimmediate@1.0.5/setImmediate.min.js')
                    importScripts('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.10.3')
                    tf.setBackend('cpu')
                    
                    const res = tf.randomNormal([2000, 2000, 3])
                    const t0 = performance.now()
                    postMessage({res: res.dataSync(), shape: res.shape})
                    console.log(`Prediction took ${(performance.now() - t0).toFixed(1)} ms`)
            };
        }
        if (window != self)
            worker_function();
    </script>
    <script>
        const worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(["(" + worker_function.toString() + ")()"], { type: 'text/javascript' })));
        worker.postMessage({});
        worker.onmessage = (message) => {
         console.log('from main thread')
         const {data} = message
         tf.tensor(message.data.res, message.data.shape)
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

We can see a difference of around 10ms between the two snippets. When performance is at cost, one needs to take into account how the data is shared if it has to be cloned or transferred.

Comment: the import script :importScripts('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/setimmediate@1.0.5/setImmediate.min.js')
                    importScripts('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.10.3')   .  I want to use the tfjs version is latest. How to change the code？

Comment: @陆一凡 Unfortunately, there is a bug which prevents the web worker to be used in the latest version tfjs@0.14.2

Comment: Now I use the function tf.loadFrozenModel() to return the model in main thread,then i want to clone or transfer the model to the webworker. How can i do it?    There is the model in my github:https://github.com/yiifanLu/webWorker

Comment: @陆一凡  Maybe you can accept this answer and create a new question for how to return the model in main thread

Answer (score 0):

TensorflowJS needs the canvas to do it's GPU computation and a worker currently doesn't have a canvas.

OffscreenCanvas is a feature that's being worked on, but before TFJS uses it, it probably needs wide enough browser support.

Comment: It needs canvas to work on GPU using webgl, but I think it can use webworker to run on CPU

Comment: Does tfjs have a CPU-only mode?

Comment: You can use tf.setBackend('cpu') to run the process only on CPU.

Comment: but now i'm failed to import the tfjs script library use self.importScripts

Comment: @陆一凡, you can see my answer !